# Performance Counter Exception on MVC Api Call

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a testing MCV Api that just returns the body and header content that was passed to it. When I try and call it I get the following exception:

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "The requested Performance Counter is not a custom counter, it has to be initialized as ReadOnly.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "StackTrace": "
      at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.InitializeImpl()
      at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.set_RawValue(Int64 value)
      at PerfIt.Handlers.CurrentConcurrentCountHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<BuildCounters>b__0()
      at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
      at PerfIt.Handlers.CurrentConcurrentCountHandler.OnRequestStarting(IDictionary`2 contextBag, PerfItContext context)
      at PerfIt.Handlers.CounterHandlerBase.OnRequestStarting(IDictionary`2 contextBag)
      at PerfIt.SimpleInstrumentor.BuildContexts()
      at PerfIt.SimpleInstrumentor.<InstrumentAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
      at PerfIt.PerfitClientDelegatingHandler.<SendAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
      at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()"
}
```

At a total loss of how to address this and any assistance would be greatly appreciated. From the googling I have done, this seams to be common as related to signalR and the fix for that had no affect here. Note: This only occurs on some Controllers in the solution, others I am able to debug against fine.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that sees this in the future. This only occurs in Debug mode. I was able to bypass this issue by commenting out the the config.MessageHandlers.Add(new PerfitClientDelegatingHandler("")) line in the WebApiConfig file.